# Can't Access Public File on Deployed Next.js App

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to set up my personal site so that viewers can click a button and download my resume. On my dev server, I simply added my `resume.pdf` to the public Next.js folder, and when I try the download, it works.

```
 <a href='/resume.pdf' download>
   <button>
     Download Resume
   </button>
 </a>
```

However, once my site gets hosted on Vercel, any time I try to download the resume, my Chrome downloader just tells me:

`404 Failed - No file`

I've noticed that this same behavior occurs whenever I try to render images out of the public folder as well.

Is there a setting in the `next.config.js` that I'm missing? I can't seem to find any useful information regarding this issue online.

Comment: Are the files accessible if you run the app in production mode locally (`next build && next start`)?

Comment: Static files are directly accessible via **yourdomain.com/filename.extension** do check if you can access yourdomain/favicon.ico or yourdomain/resume.pdf by directly opening the URL. have you uploaded the public folder at the correct place?

Comment: @juliomalves surprisingly, running in production mode (`next start`) locally actually does continue serving the static files!  So perhaps it's something else?

Comment: @Garrett Can you use a different browser? sometimes chrome extensions are creating bugs

Comment: server side, did you check if the file exists in the public folder?

Comment: @Yilmaz, ok tried in Firefox private browsing and Chromium Incognito, both still 404ed for my server, but both still work when on `localhost` (with `next start`).

Comment: @JamalEddineNaamani server-side, I don't see a `public` folder.  Locally, my folder inside `public` that the asset is in is called `img`.  Instead of `public/img` on the server, I see just `img`.  It is located next to `server.js`, `.next`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Found the issue, in our Dockerfile, we had:

```
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./
```

instead of

```
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
```

Indeed a comment above asking whether the asset was found on the server in the `public` folder was a good hint.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `resume.pdf` is directlyinside `public` folder

```
<a href='/resume.pdf' download="resume.pdf">
   <button>
     Download Resume
   </button>
 </a>
```

or you might need full url for href. Because the download attribute only works for same-origin urls. So if the href is not the same origin as the site, it won't work.

```
 <a href='https://your domain.com/resume.pdf' download="resume.pdf">
       <button>
         Download Resume
       </button>
     </a>
```

If this does not work, instead of download button, you can show the pdf file in iframe.

```
  <div>
        <iframe style={{width: '100%', height: '800px'}} src="/resume.pdf"/>
      </div>
```

Comment: Neither of those things work for me.  Locally, it does, but on the server, it doesn't.  Showing the PDF in an iframe also supposedly wouldn't work given `https://my-domain.com/resume.pdf` 404s.

Comment: @Garrett `download` attribute is causing issue. did you try iframe? it should work without absolute url. It is weird that download is not working. do you have sensitive data in your project. I want to deploy it and try to debug it

Comment: @Garrett are you able to access any other files in public folder in production

Comment: No I can't access any other files in the public folder.  I'm using `download` attribute, nor iframe, I'm simply trying to load the URL in the browser.  If that doesn't work, an iframe surely won't work either.  I can try to put together a minimal working example.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This issue may occur while using `next build`. The command `next build` does not bundle the files kept in `public` folder, rather next only introduces a mechanism internally where the next-app will try to read from `public` directory at runtime and serve the content.

So, to summarize, the public files should be present in the same folder, where `.next` folder is present, so that nextjs can pick content from it. Also, once the app is started, any new content added to public folder dynamically will not be available.

Note: In my case, i was creating `.next` under `dist` directory, while my public folder was outside `dist` and hence, nextjs was not able to serve the files properly.

Also, this works well in development mode with `next dev` without any additional configs.